# Laravel Tap Formatter: where do I actually format the message?

Tags: php, logging, laravel-5.6, formatter

In my laravel application there's need to format a message I need to send into slack. Hence I set a slack log channel into `config/logging.php`:

```
'slack'         => [
    'driver'   => 'slack',
    'url'      => /*Censored Hook URL*/,
    'username' => 'MyApp',
    'emoji'    => ':gear:',
    'level'    => 'debug',
],
```

Also as seen on [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#customizing-monolog-for-channels) I can do a monolog formater, hence I did the following:

```
namespace App\Logging;

class SlackLogFormatter
{
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            $handler->setFormatter(...);
        }
    }
}
```

And specified it as tap into my log:

```
'slack'         => [
    'driver'   => 'slack',
    'tap' => [App\Logging\SlackLogFormatter::class]
    'url'      => /*Censored Hook URL*/,
    'username' => 'MyApp',
    'emoji'    => ':gear:',
    'level'    => 'debug',
],
```

But in my formater where do I process the log entry itself? I mean:

1. The `$handler->setFormatter` does not seem to be a method of `\Illuminate\Log\Logger` class.
2. I cannot find out what method I need to override when I need to provide a custom format.  I mean I have the invoke method then afterwards what?

Comment: Funnily enough I have exactly the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formatter for slack should be the following:

```
namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class SlackLogFormatter
{
    /**
     * Customize the given logger instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Log\Logger  $logger
     * @return void
     */
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            if ($handler instanceof SlackWebhookHandler) {
                $format=""; // Look on the Monolog's Line formatter documentation
                $formatter= new LineFormatter($format,"Y-m-d H:i:s");


                $handler->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
                   //Append extra info of formatting here
                });

                $handler->setFormatter($formatter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And config the slack not to send attachment nessesary for the formatter to work:

```
'slack'         => [
    'driver'   => 'slack',
    'tap' => [App\Logging\SlackLogFormatter::class]
    'url'      => /*Censored Hook URL*/,
    'username' => 'MyApp',
    'emoji'    => ':gear:',
    'level'    => 'debug',
    'attachment' => FALSE,
],
```

The `setFormatter` method takes a new Monolog Formatter as seen in: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#formatters

Also the `pushProcessor` allows you to populate extra fields on your message eg. Showing an emoji on your log message:

```
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            if ($handler instanceof SlackWebhookHandler) {
                $format="%emoji% %message%"; 
                $formatter= new LineFormatter($format,"Y-m-d H:i:s");

                $handler->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
                         $record['emoji']=":poop:";
                });

                $handler->setFormatter($formatter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: when i keep the pushProcessor part, i have this error:
` Return value of Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler::processRecord() must be of the type array, null returned
`

Answer (score 3):

Dimitrios is almost right (or perhaps this worked on older versions) but as Xavier said, if you copy that code exactly you will get the error

```
Return value of Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler::processRecord() must be of the type array, null returned
```

You are going to want to do something like this instead :

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\SlackWebhookHandler;
use Request;

class CustomiseFormatter
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request = null)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            if ($handler instanceof SlackWebhookHandler) {
                $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(
                    '[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %context% %extra%'
                ));

                $handler->pushProcessor([$this, 'processLogRecord']);
            }
        }
    }

    public function processLogRecord(array $record): array
    {
        $record['extra'] += [
            'url' => env("APP_URL"),
        ];

        return $record;
    }
}
```

Equally, as with how `extra` has be modified, you can change any other value.

Comment: Mine was tested upon Laravel 5.7 version and earlier.